# How to deal with special "constant" instances of object when using DI

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection

My project is heavily using dependency injection, and I'm being very careful to avoid service locator antipattern. All objects are structured using constructor injection that allow easily identifiable list of dependencies. Now I'm building an object, and it has a special "constant" instance, which is basically static/singleton (consider example of something like Integer.MinValue). So my initial reflex was to create a static field with a static "getter" method, which would create the instance of the object if it wasn't previously created. The object itself has dependencies however, so I'm confused on what's the best practice for instantiating this "special instance". I'm looking for recommendations on how to best structure code in this scenario, ideally without having to call upon the container for resolution of dependencies. Some code:

```
public class PressureUnit extends DataUnit {
    private static PressureUnit standardAtmosphere;
    public static PressureUnit StandardAtmosphere() {
        if(standardAtmosphere == null){
            standardAtmosphere = new PressureUnit(1013.25); // this line is what is bothering me as I need to resolve other dependencies (have to use new as it's a static method and can't be injected like everywhere else)
        }
        return standardAtmosphere;
    }

    @AssistedInject
    public PressureUnit(ITimeProvider timeProvider, IUnitProvider unitProvider, @Assisted double value) {
        this(timeProvider, unitProvider, value, PressureUnits.hPa);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can either initialize the static StandardAtmosphere value when the DI container is being built or you can have the StandardAtmosphere value be a singleton registration in the DI container.

Comment: I just feel these constants are part of business logic, and sticking them in a dependency resolution module registration (which is the case of container i'm using - guice, would have to be in a @Provides method inside module). Putting this in module feels like I'm putting business logic outside of where it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't see any problem in your code since you are not newing up dependencies here and there, now with that being said i can give some suggestions:

- If you specifically want the container to call an existing static factory method, you can use [StaticFactoryExtension](http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2009/06/15/unity-static-factory-extension/).
- Why don't you use a factory.
- Consider refactoring you design and removing the static method if possible.